# ReactJS nuke carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am interested in getting this react js nuke carousel working.  https://github.com/kenwheeler/nuka-carousel

//jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/6/

Is there a cdn I could tap into to load in the module?

```
var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel');

var CarouselApp = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Carousel.ControllerMixin],
  render() {
    return (
      <Carousel>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"/>
      </Carousel>
    )
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <CarouselApp name="CarouselApp" />,
  document.getElementById('CarouselApp')
);
```

Comment: I would like to get it working in jsfiddle - essentially independent from an npm server

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel')

But there are no 'nuka-carousel' library installed on jsfiddle server. You need to load 'nuka-carousel' from external dependency as babel like this:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>
```

And there is no `require` function defined in jsfiddle-integration-babel.js

Comment: what would be the external dependency

Comment: I meant like cdn link

Comment: Wasn't really asking to make a lib - was saying how to get it working on jsfiddle if there was an external cdn for it